# How to change background image in JS depending on input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background image of a site based on the input the user types in. For example, if the user types in New York or New York City or NYC, the background image changes to a picture of NYC.

I'm very new to JS and haven't gotten the hang of it yet. I've tried using the `if/else if` and the `||` operators for the inputs but doesn't seem to work.

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="city-type" placeholder="Enter a city name...">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" id="submit-btn">
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var city = $('#city-type').val();
    $('#city-type').val('');
  });

  function cityBackground(citytype) {
    if (citytype === 'New York' || citytype === 'New York City' || citytype === 'NYC') {
      $('body').css('background', '../images/nyc.jpg') no - repeat;
    } else if (citytype === 'San Francisco' || citytype === 'SF' || citytype === 'Bay Area') {
      $('body').css('background', '../images/sf.jpg') no - repeat;
    }
  });
```

Comment: it doesn't look like you're calling function `cityBackground()` -- in your `$('.container').click( ... )` add a line like `cityBackground( city )`

Comment: You are not passing the event variable to your .click() callback. Not that you need to call preventDefault anyway. Also your .css() call on $(body) is wrong the no - repeat would be parsed as var no (minus) var repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As mentioned by @GifCo you need to pass an `event` in the `.click( function(event) )` so that the code has the target to `preventDefault` (otherwise it will just submit the whole page as a standard HTML form.
2. In your `click` you need to call your `cityBackground` function and pass it the value that you're measuring the code against.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.container').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var city = $('#city-type').val();
    cityBackground(city);
    $('#city-type').val('');
  });

  function cityBackground(citytype) {
    if (citytype === 'New York' || citytype === 'New York City' || citytype === 'NYC') {
      // $('body').css('background-image', '../images/nyc.jpg');
      console.log( 'New York City' );
    } else if (citytype === 'San Francisco' || citytype === 'SF' || citytype === 'Bay Area') {
      // $('body').css('background-image', '../images/sf.jpg');
      console.log( 'San Francisco' );
    }
  }
  
});
```

```css
body{
  background-image: url( '' );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="city-type" placeholder="Enter a city name...">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" id="submit-btn">
  </form>
</div>
```

Some extra bits of info to consider...

The data that the user types in may not be predictable.  It may be worth looking into comparisons after mutating the text (string) into all [uppercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) or all [lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

```
var city = ( $('#city-type').val() ).toUpperCase();
// ...
if( citytype === 'NEW YORK' || ... || ... )
```

But there's also a lot of unpredictable ways a user may fill out the form.  NY, NYC, New York, New York City, Big Apple, The Big Apple, ...

If possible, I would recommend a [select list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: Thank you! @GifCo and Doug for pointing out I was not calling the right function, adding cityBackground(city) and passing (event) in the .click function worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

the CSS property for background image is `background-image: url("image.gif");`
So your jQuery statements would like like this:
`$('body').css('background-image', 'url(../images/nyc.jpg)').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');`

Comment: What if I wanted to change the background image using jQuery statements instead of the CSS? I tried this instead and it works fine but is there another way you'd suggest. document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/nyc.jpg')";

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a form, submit would be a better event handler than click. A nice habit to get into when comparing strings is using trim and toLowerCase to remove outer whitespace and allow for case-insensitive searching. I also used indexOf instead of a bunch of string comparisons.

```js
$('#cityForm').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var city = $('#city-type').val().trim().toLowerCase();
  $('#city-type').val('');
  cityBackground(city)
});

function cityBackground(city) {
  console.log(city);
  if (['new york', 'new york city', 'nyc'].indexOf(city) != -1) {
    $('body').css('background', 'red');
  } else if (['bay area', 'san fransisco', 'sf'].indexOf(city) != -1) {
      $('body').css('background', 'gray');
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form id="cityForm">
    <input type="text" id="city-type" placeholder="Enter a city name...">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" id="submit-btn">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a very helpful reminder! I will try .indexOf(city), and I was wondering what does the != -1 add?

Comment: indexOf will return the position of the item in the array, or -1 if it is not in there

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have many answers, here is my approach. At least you can choose what you like and learn something from each.

```js
$('#cityForm').on('submit', changeBg);

function changeBg(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  switch($('#city-type').val()) {
    case 'nyc':
      $('body').css('background-image', "url('https://media.cntraveler.com/photos/5a8f3b070e2cf839e9dbfa1d/master/w_1200,c_limit/NYC_GettyImages-640006562.jpg')");
      break;
    case 'tokyo':
      $('body').css('background-image', "url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2400/1*vOrfclMVms7S4608zxC-ig.jpeg')");
      break;
    default:
      $('body').css('background-image', 'none');
      
  }
  
  $('#city-type').val('');
  

}
```

```css
body {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form id="cityForm">
    <input type="text" id="city-type" placeholder="Enter a city name...">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" id="submit-btn">
  </form>
</div>
```